# Dart: search value in list

Tags: flutter, dart

Having the next list, how can get `uno` by searching by `un` (like `contains3`)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `any` operator

```
var contains1 = array.any((item)=>item.contains("un"));
print(contains1);// true
```

> any : Checks every element in iteration order, and returns true if any of them make test return true, otherwise returns false.